# Finding unique entries in a text file

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a file I've imported into the console: I wish to search it for unique entries such as:

```
tom 
tim
tim
tom
alan
```

When I search the file I want to count the number of unique lines in the file.

I'm using `.NET Framework 3.5` so I can't use `System.Linq`. Any suggestions? Other than upgrading to `.NET 4`?

Comment: .NET 3.5 provides of LINQ, what is the problem with LINQ?

Comment: I Tried it on my college computers whichhas 3.5 and it did not exist?

Comment: @Evildommer5 : you need to ensure that C# Project's target framework version is set to 3.5

Comment: `I Tried it on my college computers whichhas 3.5 and it did not exist?` I tried on my computer and it **did exist**

Comment: @Sll and Evildommer5 will also need to ensure that the correct assembly is referenced -- `System.Core.dll` if I recall correctly?

Comment: That doesn't exist in my directory apperently :/

Comment: Maybe the college computers are 3.0?

Comment: @Evildommer5 from your comments here it appears that you don't yet understand assembly references and using directives very well.  I would recommend that you read up on these basic concepts.

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly simple with the LINQ extension methods [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) and [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx):

```
int numberOfUniqueLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Distinct().Count();
```

Regarding this:

> im using framework 3.5 so cant use system.linq any suggestions?

LINQ *is* available in .NET 3.5. However if you are using .NET 2.0 you can use a dictionary instead:

```
Dictionary<string, object> uniqueLines = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)) {
    uniqueLines[line] = null;
}
int numberOfUniqueLines = uniqueLines.Keys.Count;
```

Comment: Add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: @sll does <string, object>  need to be replaced with soemthing?

Comment: @Evildommer5 no, `<string, object>` does not need to be replaced.  Mark is just using the Dictionary like a HashSet (the underlying implementation is the same).  This is useful because Dictionary was introduced earlier (in .NET 2.0).  He's assigning the value `null` to all keys, since the Value functionality is redundant in this application.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the lines in the file.
Add each line to a `HashSet<string>`.
Return the `Count` property of the `HashSet<string>`.

Example:

```
int lineCount = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fileName)).Count;
```

EDIT I originally had `File.ReadLines` since that would use less memory if you have a lot of duplicate lines.  That method was introduced with .NET 4, so it's not available under the stated requirements.

EDIT2 System.Core.dll is part of framework 3.5, so you really ought to be able to find it somewhere (the GAC, perhaps?).  If you can't however, you could achieve your goal by loading the lines into a `List<string>`, sorting it, and then counting items only if they are not the same as the previous item (note that this fails if any item in the list is null):

```
var list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fileName));
list.Sort();
var counter = 0;
string previousItem = null;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item.Equals(previousItem))
        continue;
    counter++;
    previousItem = item;
}
return counter;
```

Comment: So this does not use system.linq?

Comment: Correct.  But in .NET 3.5, the `HashSet<>` collection was also defined in System.Core.dll, so you'll need to reference that for both this solution and the Linq solution.

Comment: in my compiler System.Core.dll does not exist

Comment: In that case, perhaps you should post another StackOverflow question along the lines of "Can't find System.Core.dll in .NET Framework 3.5"

Comment: When i put in return counter; it comes up with an error that it cant be used.

Comment: `System.Collections.Hashtable` exists since 1.0 :)

Comment: The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) - \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Assigment\Assigment\Program.cs:40,23

Comment: @Evildommer5 Very good idea not to mention that you are using `SharpDevelop`, maybe people can find an answer :)